# Angular 2 How to Concatenate an index into an object and its array using Ng For

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, iteration

I dynamically created an array using rows and columns

```
[
  {
    "name": "table 1",
    "rows": [
      "row 1",
      "row 2",
      "row 3",
      "row 4",
      "row 5"
    ],
    "columns": [
      "column 1",
      "column 2"
    ],
      "col1": [
      {
        "1": "row1col1"
      },
      {
        "2": "row2col1"
      },
      {
        "3": "row3col1"
      },
      {
        "4": "row4col1"
      },
      {
        "5": "row5col1"
      }
    ],
      "col2": [
      {
        "1": "row1col2"
      },
      {
        "2": "row2col2"
      },
      {
        "3": "row3col2"
      },
      {
        "4": "row4col2"
      },
      {
        "5": "row5col2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "table 2",
    "rows": [
      "row 1",
      "row 2",
    ],
    "columns": [
      "column 1",
      "column 2",
      "column 3"
    ],
      "col1": [
      {
        "1": "row1col1"
      },
      {
        "2": "row2col1"
    ],
      "col2": [
      {
        "1": "row1col2"
      },
      {
        "2": "row2col2"
    ],
      "col3": [
      {
        "1": "row1col3"
      },
      {
        "2": "row2col3"
    ]
  }
 ]
```

Then using this dynamic array I created a table and stored it as finalArray
which was okay until I went to the body of my table to show data for col and row

```
<div *ngFor="let table of finalArray">
     <span>{{table.name}}</span>

      <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
             <tr>
               <th scope="col"></th>
               <th *ngFor="let column of table.columns" scope="col">{{column}}</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let row of table.rows ; let i = index">
         <td>{{row}}</td> // this works fine
         <td *ngFor="let column of table.columns; let x = index"> {{table.['col' + x].[i+1]}}</td> 
      // this is the problem
      </tr>

     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note that the array was created dynamically so rows and columns is not fixed and col1 and col2 was created based on columns.

I attempt to something like table.col[index].[loop all values]?

Comment: which array contains `table.columns` can you mention here..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Iterate thru columns in the second loop for more precision. Remove '.'s when getting elements. Interchange + 1 from i to x when getting columns and use Object.keys to get the array of key names so you can get the corresponding column content. I put it in a method for for readability

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th *ngFor="let column of table.columns" scope="col">{{column}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of table.rows ; let i = index">
                <td>{{row}}</td>
                <td *ngFor="let col of table.columns; let x = index">
                    {{getColumnContent(table['col'+(x+1)][i])}}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

**Typescript**

```
  getColumnContent(col) {
    return col[Object.keys(col)[0]] // always [0] as it contains a single element
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlmuki)