# Typescript Sort and Rank Array of Objects

Tags: typescript, sorting

I'm kinda new to angular and I recently have a code that push an array of object into a new array.

```
mainArr.Survey.forEach(item => {
    newArray.push({
        list: item.data.map((option: any) => {
            const target = this.dataArray.find(x => x.name === item.name && option == x.value);
            return {
                [option]: target ? target.count : 0
            }
        })
    });
});
```

this output as follows:

```
"list": [
      {
        "1": "37"
      },
      {
        "2": "45"
      },
      {
        "3": "12"
      },
      {
        "4": "21"
      },
      {
        "5": "21"
      }
    ],
```

is there a way that instead of the count it will return its rank from other object values (highest to lowest)? like this?

```
 "list": [
      {
        "1": "2" //37
      },
      {
        "2": "1" //45
      },
      {
        "3": "4" //12
      },
      {
        "4": "3" //21
      },
      {
        "5": "3" //21
      }
    ],
```

Comment: What is you data structure?

Comment: It is the same as this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072042/angular-2-how-to-concatenate-an-index-into-an-object-and-its-array-using-ng-for/51077452#51077452](Link) list = col1